# change state while preserving previous state

Tags: reactjs

I'm using hooks to change the state like this:

```
 const [fieldValues, setFieldValues] = useState([{}]); 


const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFieldValues( prev => ([...prev, {value : e.target.value , field: e.target.name , project : e.target.id} ]))
}
```

My form is like this:

```
          <form>
                    <textarea defaultValue = {project.fieldKpi.value ? project.fieldKpi.value : null}  name={project.fieldKpi.id} id={project.projectId} onChange = {handleChange}></textarea>
                    <textarea defaultValue = {project.fieldContract ? project.fieldContract.value : null}  name={project.fieldContract.id} id={project.projectId} onChange = {handleChange}></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Opslaan"/>
                </form>
```

When i change the form the onchange triggers and i get this error:

[image]

what i want is an array of multipje different objects unless they're the same then dont add a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is issue of **[Event Pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)** :

> The SyntheticEvent is pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent
>   object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the
>   event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As
>   such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.

**Solution :**

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { value , name , id } = event.target; // <---- HERE
    setFieldValues( prev => ([...prev, {value : value , field: name , project : id} ]))
}
```

Comment: Very nice catch, well played